# What are the differences between ConfigureServices() and Configure() in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The documentation on learn.microsoft.com states the following:

> Use ConfigureServices method to add services to the container.
>
> Use Configure method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.

Can someone explain with simple examples, what is meant by adding services to container and what is meant by configuring HTTP request pipeline?

Comment: Documentation [Application startup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: ...and it also includes examples as requested.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

In a nutshell:

`ConfigureServices` is used to configure Dependency Injection

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // register MVC services
    services.AddMvc();

    // register configuration
    services.Configure<AppConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("RestCalls")); 

    // register custom services
    services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    ...
}
```

`Configure` is used to set up middlewares, routing rules, etc

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // configure middlewares
    app.UseMiddleware<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware>();
    app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandleMiddleware>();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    // setup routing
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            template: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 1 });

    });
}
```

Read [ASP.NET Core fundamentals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/) to understand how it works in details.

Comment: Interesting that the DI methods are mostly "Add..." and the middleware methods are mostly "Use...". Makes sense.

Comment: @Alex Riabov   does `ConfigureServices` only involve `DI`? how about `services.AddIdentity`, is any 'DI' involved?

Comment: @secondimage, yes eventually it registers Authentication services: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core/AuthenticationCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

Comment: @AlexRiabov  I didn't see `.AddIdentity`, only see `.AddAuthenticationCore`

Comment: it's called from `AddAuthentication` (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) which is called from `AddAuthentication` https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

Comment: is `ConfigureServices` executed before or after `Configure` ?

Comment: The `ConfigureServices` method is called by the host before the `Configure` method to configure the app's services. source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-configureservices-method

Answer (score 29):

Items in `ConfigureServices` are part of `Dependency Injection` like logger, Database etc. These kind of things aren't **directly** associated with a http request.

Items in `configure` are part of a **http request** like routing, mididlewares, static files all these triggers directly when user makes a request.

Comment: I like this short and direct answer.